Composition of operators is compact
Let $A$ be a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. If  $T:\mathcal{H}\mapsto\mathcal{K}$ is compact, how do I show that $TA$ is compact? I was able to show the case for $BT$ where $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{K})$, but I'm not sure how to show the reverse, $TA$. Let $ball \ \mathcal{H}$ be the closed unit ball in $\mathcal{H}$. Right now I'm thinking along the lines of
$$\overline{A(ball \ \mathcal{H})}\subseteq\{k\in\mathcal{K}:||k||\leq C\}=D$$
so
$$T(A(ball \ \mathcal{H}))\subseteq T(\overline{A(ball \ \mathcal{H})})\subseteq T(D)$$
and then show that $\overline{T(D)}$ is compact, but I'm not really sure how to go about this or if its the correct approach.

If your definition of compactness is that T(unit ball) is compact, then note that $D$ is $C$ times a unit ball, and due to linearity of $T$, $T(D) = C \cdot T(\text{unit ball})$. (Note also that scaling a compact set in Hilbert space remains compact)

ahhh yea i thought that that made sense but i wasnt sure if scaling was compact

scaling is continuous and continuous map sends compact set to compact set
